# Missing keyword exception Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, case

Why this query returns missing keyword error with Oracle Database:

Note: Case condition is being used to select an appropriate where statement for WHERE condition. This is a mysql query which I am migrating to Oracle.

```
SELECT OFFICE_TYPE_CD, OFFICE_TYPE_DESC
  FROM m_office_types
 WHERE     CASE
               WHEN OFFICE_TYPE_CD IN (7)
               THEN
                   office_level_cd < (SELECT DISTINCT office_level_cd
                                        FROM m_office_types
                                       WHERE     office_type_cd = 7
                                             AND RECORD_STATUS <> 'D')
               ELSE
                   office_level_cd <= (SELECT DISTINCT office_level_cd
                                         FROM m_office_types
                                        WHERE     office_type_cd = 7
                                              AND RECORD_STATUS <> 'D')
           END
       AND RECORD_STATUS = 'C'
       AND state_cd = 27
       AND OFFICE_NAME IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Care to share the schema please!

Comment: What should the `CASE` do? This says that `if OFFICE_TYPE_CD IN (7)` the `CASE` value should be `office_level_cd < (...)` which makes no sense. Try to explain what you need to do with this query

Comment: Because of incorrect usage of the `case` expression. The `missing keyword` error is raised because you put comparison operator in the `then` clause of the case expression. When you fix this `Invalid relational operator` will be raised because in the `where` clause you have to compare result of the `case` expression to something.

Comment: There is no PL/SQL in your question. I am also very sure that not even MySQL would allow to run that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to write something like this:

```
SELECT OFFICE_TYPE_CD, OFFICE_TYPE_DESC
  FROM m_office_types
 WHERE     RECORD_STATUS = 'C'
       AND state_cd = 27
       AND OFFICE_NAME IS NOT NULL
       AND (   (    OFFICE_TYPE_CD IN (7)
                AND office_level_cd < (SELECT DISTINCT office_level_cd
                                         FROM m_office_types
                                        WHERE     office_type_cd = 7
                                              AND RECORD_STATUS <> 'D'))
            OR (    OFFICE_TYPE_CD NOT IN (7)
                AND office_level_cd <= (SELECT DISTINCT office_level_cd
                                          FROM m_office_types
                                         WHERE     office_type_cd = 7
                                               AND RECORD_STATUS <> 'D')))
```

Pease notice that it can be simplified, I only wrote like that for clarity